# Colocar lista de categorias en el nav Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy haciendo una app de noticias para practicar.

Quiero que en el nav aparezcan todas las categorías pero no se como. Probé usando un listview pero no se como implementarlo dentro del nav.

La idea es que al entrar a la categoría salgan todos los posts de esa categoría.

Dejo el models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/images')

    content = models.TextField()

    published = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuve que poner en la view el metodo get_context_data:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['categories_list'] = Category.objects.all()
    return context
```

Y para que se vean los posts de esa sola categoria use:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, title=self.kwargs['category'])
    return Post.objects.filter(category=category)
```

Y la url:

```
path(
    route='post/<str:category>/',
    view=views.CategoriesFeedView.as_view(),
    name='category'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creas un view para enlazar los datos del modal con el template

```
from app.models import Category


def index(request):

    category_list = Category.objects.order_by('title')
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')

    context = {

        'category_list': category_list
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

En el template agregar algo asi

```
{% for category in category_list %}
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"style="color:{{configuracion_general.color_texto_navbar}}">
          {{ category.title }}
        </a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: No me funciona, alguna idea? Te dejo el codigo:
`def categories(request):

    category_list = Category.objects.order_by('title')
    template = loader.get_template('feed/base.html')

    context = {
        'category_list': category_list
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))`


` {% for category in category_list %}
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                {{ category.title }}
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}`

Comment: No me deja escribir bien el codigo, pero igual creo que se logra entender